# how to condition same time data to insert and update in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I will try If on today's date, any row insert Then update value use id
And if not any row today's date Then insert a new row.  but the problem is update value is working but not insert a new row message is "Trying to get property 'Date' of non-object"

```
public function present($id){
  $user = User::find($id);
  $date = date('Y-m-d');
  $id = $user->id;
  $Attendance= Attendance::where('User_A_ID','=',$id)->first();
  
  if($Attendance->Date == $date){
        $Attendance->A_sts = '0';
        $Attendance->Date = $date;
        $Attendance->User_A_ID = $user->id;
        $Attendance->save();
  } else {
        $Attendance= new Attendance();
        $Attendance->A_sts = '0';
        $Attendance->Date = $date;
        $Attendance->User_A_ID = $user->id;
        $Attendance->save();
  }
  return back();
}
```

Comment: try `findOrFail()` instead of only `find()`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you want to update the existing attendance that belongs to the user or create a new attendance if the user does not have one.

You can simplify your code:

```
public function present($id)
{
    $user = User::findOrFail($id);
    $date = date('Y-m-d');

    $Attendance = Attendance::firstOrNew(['User_A_ID' => $user->id, 'Date', $date]);

    $Attendance->User_A_ID = $user->id;
    $Attendance->Date = $date;
    $Attendance->A_sts = '0';
    $Attendance->save();

    return back();
}
```

Use `findOrFail` to check if the user exists, and then use `firstOrNew` to retrieve the existing attendance for today or create a new instance of it, this way you can get rid of your `if` statement.

Comment: Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::firstOrNew(), 0 passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\app\app\Http\Controllers\UserController.php on line 330 and at least 1 expected 
firstOrNew();

Comment: @MdTouhidulIslam Oops, my mistake. Could you try again with the updated code.